# Subimage - Get Rid of White Space

Tags: image, matlab, whitespace

I want to subplot several images together. But using `subimage` decreases the quality of the image and there is a lot of unnecessary white space. It's so small that I can't read it.

How can I get rid of the white space and plot the images as close as possible? Only one colorbar is really needed.

```
addpath(genpath('/home/jg3223/Documents/EPA_AQSData/US/PM2.5/Plots_PM25_24hr/'))

[X1,map1]=imread('map_US_1997_AnnualAvg_PM25_24hr.jpg');
[X2,map2]=imread('map_US_1997_Spring_PM25_24hr.jpg');
[X3,map3]=imread('map_US_1997_Summer_PM25_24hr.jpg');
[X4,map4]=imread('map_US_1997_Fall_PM25_24hr.jpg');
[X5,map5]=imread('map_US_1998_Winter_PM25_24hr.jpg');

subplot(1,5,1), imshow(X1,map1)
subplot(1,5,2), imshow(X2,map2)
subplot(1,5,3), imshow(X1,map3)
subplot(1,5,4), imshow(X2,map4)
subplot(1,5,5), imshow(X1,map5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to reduce whitespace is to check your jpeg images to make sure that they don't have unnecessary borders. You could also remove the colorbar from all but one of them.

For a more automated approach, you can implement subplot a little differently.

```
positionVector = [fromleft frombottom width height];
subplot('position',positionVector); imshow(X1,map1);
```

based on [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html#btw2bh4-1) documentation it appears that the units are in percentage of the total figure size.